# Dockerized Django app not running in Azure

Tags: django, azure, docker

I'm trying to deploy a Django app dockerized to Azure App Service, the app seems to run well on my local environment `http://localhost:8000/`, for this I use `docker run -p 8000:8000 myapp.azurecr.io/myapp:latest`. But when I try deploying the app to Azure it doesn't work.

This is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update \&& apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev libffi-dev freetype-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev build-base \&& pip install --upgrade pip psycopg2-binary

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And these are the logs I receive from Azure

```
2022-11-25T00:33:44.857803391Z Performing system checks...
2022-11-25T00:33:44.857871092Z
2022-11-25T00:33:48.431821909Z System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2022-11-25T00:33:48.890144064Z November 25, 2022 - 00:33:48
2022-11-25T00:33:48.896514773Z Django version 4.0.3, using settings 'certificados.settings'
2022-11-25T00:33:48.896531175Z Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
2022-11-25T00:33:48.896535775Z Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

...

Container myapp_0_aaaaa didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 3000, failing site start.
```

I'm new to Docker so I don't know if I'm missing something important here.

Comment: Your container exposes port 3000 and Azure seems to expect the app to be accessible on that port but your app is running on port 8000, change your app to run on port 3000?

Comment: now that you mention it seems so obvious, thank you this worked!

Comment: I think you can post this as an answer so I can accept it